# How to configure database in Baeldung spring-security-registration application?

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to train myself on Spring security and started looking at Baeldung.com website and examples posted for public download at github repository https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-registration. I downloaded the source code in this repository as ZIP and imported in netbeans. Following the instructions in README.md, I built it using mvn clean install. Application spring-security-login-and-registration downloaded all dependencies and built clean. But I don't have a clue how to configure the MySQL database needed for this application.

Do I need to download MySQL server and have a server instance on my localhost?
If yes, where would I get the scripts to create the schema/tables needed in the security application? I can't find the scripts anywhere in source code. Anything similar to hSQL going on here?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need to download MySql from here https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html.

And need to configure few things during installation like username and password.
And update these fields inside you database properties file.

```
################### DataSource Configuration ##########################

jdbc.driverClassName=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YourDatabaseName?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
jdbc.user=YourUserNameForMySql
jdbc.pass=PasswordHere
```

You can start you mysql on windows by executing this command:-
`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe"` on command prompt

Meanwhile you can login to mysql shell using this below command on terminal:-

```
mysql -uroot -proot
```